# Structure from Motion (openCV): ‘reconstruct’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, ceres-solver

I'm a beginner with opencv library. I've installed it on Ubuntu 17.04 and everything during the installation was perfect, no error at all. I've installed the Opencv-master, builded it, then I downloaded the opencv_contrib-master and everything was perfect..

I'm trying to build the scene_reconstruction using SFM (structure for motion). I've installed all the dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev
```

Then I've installed the Ceres Solver:

```
git clone https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver
cd ceres-solver
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
make test
sudo make install
```

Everything was ok, no error at all. I tried to write the example_sfm_scene_reconstruction.cpp following the official documentation from here ([Scene Reconstruction](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d18/tutorial_sfm_scene_reconstruction.html)) named it **Reconstruct.cpp**.

I wrote the **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project( Reconstruct )

include_directories( /usr/local/include/eigen3 )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package( Eigen3 REQUIRED )
add_executable( Reconstruct Reconstruct.cpp )
target_link_libraries( Reconstruct ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I've created the build directory and opened it with `mkdir build && cd build`.
Then `cmake ..`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.3.1") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/simocolna/Scrivania/SFM/build
```

But when I try to do `make` I have this error:

```
error: ‘reconstruct’ was not declared in this scope
 econstruct(images_paths, Rs_est, ts_est, K,
points3d_estimated,is_projective);
```

I tried to follow this forum [issue 476](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/476) but anything helped me.

Comment: Try adding `find_package( Ceres REQUIRED )` in your CMakeLists.txt. If ceres is not found the reconstruction headers won't be included with sfm

Comment: Ceres is found. The result of that instruction is:

`Found required Ceres dependency: gflags
-- Found Ceres version: 1.13.0 installed in: /usr/local with components: [LAPACK, SuiteSparse, SparseLinearAlgebraLibrary, CXSparse, SchurSpecializations, OpenMP]`

Answer (score 1):

add

```
#define CERES_FOUND 1
```

before your code